# Ncurses menu with linked string

Tags: c++, ncurses

Id like to have linked string in my ncurses menu to something like:

```
/bin
/hello
/home
...
```

And i have vector of components named `w_files` which have variable `name` (bin, hello, home, ...) and when i do this:

```
chdir(w_actDir.c_str());
this->selected = 0;
unsigned int n_choices = w_files.size();
my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(n_choices+1, sizeof(ITEM *));
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n_choices; ++i){
    string toShow = w_files[i]->getName();
    my_items[i] = new_item(toShow.c_str(), "");
}


my_menu = new_menu((ITEM**)my_items);

set_menu_mark(my_menu, "");
set_menu_win(my_menu, this->w_window);
set_menu_format(my_menu, LINES-5, 1);
int center = COLS/2;
set_menu_sub(my_menu, derwin(this->w_window, LINES-5, center-5, 3, 1));

post_menu(my_menu);
wrefresh(this->w_window);
```

its ok, result looks:

```
bin
hello
home
...
```

But when change line `string toShow = w_files[i]->getName();` to `string toShow = "/" + w_files[i]->getName();`

Result is:
[image]

Can anybody help me, please?
Thank you.

Comment: You should actually get warnings, if not errors about that. It's because `"/"` is not a `std::string` so you can't use it first in an concatenation expression. It's even worse if `getName` doesn't return a `std::string` as you then try to add two pointers. Try instead `std::string("/") + ...`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: not working... i dont get any warnings and i compile witch -Wall -pedantic... method getName returns string

Comment: Is it important for you to store directory names without "/"?

Comment: @Losiowaty yes, because it is a simple file manager and when copying or moving it will be problem..

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after posting the comment I had an idea for an answer - the safest way would be appending to `toShow` string.

Code sample:

```
string toShow = "/";
toShow.append(w_files[i]->getName());
```

Comment: not working, too... however, i've resolved it by this way: `my_items[i] = new_item("/", w_files[i]->getName().c_str());` i know it isnt the best option, but it works...

Comment: Well, I've checked in the docs, and it seems that your first way (and also my solution) did not have a chance to work, because `new_item` doesn't copy the string it is passed, it only stores a pointer to it, so you have to ensure that the memory is valid throoughout the items lifetime, and with your first attempt to create the string within for-loop, meant that it was also desttoyed after the loop ended.  I'm quite sure that for this reason, the way you pass "/" is also prone to errors.